# Azure SQL is not returning the result

Tags: azure-sql-database, azure-sql

I have a simple query like below

```
select * from regulation where description = 'Regulation (EU) 2016'

select * from regulation where description like '%Regulation (EU)%'

select * from regulation where description like '%Regulation (E%'
```

None of the above query is returning the result.

However, when I do

```
    select * from regulation where description like '%Regulation%'
```

The result is getting returned as,  **Regulation (EU) 2016**

I checked if there is any space or any other char, but nothing is present. The description type in table is **(nvarchar(max),null)**

It's quite strange, I'm confused and never seen such problem. Did anyone faced similar problem ? Or, am I doing something wrong? Or, is it something Azure SQL setting or cache related and I need to ask DBA for re-indexing?

Comment: Have you checked what characters the `(EU)` in the result are? Maybe they are non-ascii characters that look like an E and a U that don't match your query.

Comment: How to check what characters the (EU)?  mean from ASCII table? the looks like its a bug. When I'm trying to update just (EU) using an update query. Its updating/showing as (?U)  -any idea why?

Comment: Maybe the db has some weird collation set. If you right-click on it in SSMS, you should see it in the General tab. It would normally be something like `SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS`.

Comment: You could try forcing the collation of your query. `WHERE [Column X] = [Column Y] COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AS`. Taken from https://www.sqlshack.com/sql-server-collation-introduction-with-collate-sql-casting/

Comment: Checked. Here is the collection :  "SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS" from the Database properties. And, compatibility level SQL Server 2017 (140)